# Compile for Mac from Linux / Windows

Tags: linux, macos

Is there any way to generate binaries from c++ code for mac from linux / windows ?

Currently we want to give away reference implementations and we dont have mac but participants do have. Hence this problem.

Comment: Build a cross-compiler. http://bit.ly/VwyE1O

Comment: @BenjiWiebe, that is far from enough it the objective is to build some native GUI application...

Comment: I think, running OS X in a VM is the best (err.) solution. I don't which the best way of doing it, someone?

Comment: If you want to build a native GUI application, you need an SDK, and you're not allowed to install the SDK except by installing Xcode, and you can only install Xcode on a Mac. Meanwhile, how are you even writing native GUI code if you don't have a Mac? Are you just crossing your fingers and hoping it works?

Comment: Also: How many hours of work and frustration is it worth it for you to save the $100 it costs to get a used Mid 2007 Mac Mini?

Answer (score 0):

If you have C++ code you can [cross-compile](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler&ei=MswKUbC1LtSWhQeDwYHwDQ&usg=AFQjCNEr47oVnsOKgrBrObczlSy2BPGuFw&sig2=cxOG5GmSWlTPY1PP7GyBSA&bvm=bv.41642243,d.ZG4) from almost any machine to another machine. I suppose you can generate binaries from a mac machine to a linux/windows machine.

Comment: This isn't true in practice, at least to not any useful extent.

Answer (score 0):

Not reliably -- and, even if you could, you'd have no way to test them. Either find some friendly person with a Mac you can use to build and test your application, or don't distribute a Mac version.